# Autostarting .desktop application at startup not working

Tags: ubuntu, .desktop, xdg

I have read that adding a `.desktop` file to `/etc/xdg/autostart` can start an application at startup. I did the same to execute my application. But nothing happens on startup. Following is the content of my `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=screenshot
Exec=/home/anaswara/eclipse_agent/bin/Screenshot
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel
```

Can anybody tell what is going wrong(`Ubunu 14.04`)

Comment: Is `/home/anaswara/eclipse_agent/bin/Screenshot` an executable and working fine with terminal? or Is this `.desktop` works with normal way?

Comment: that is an executable and works from terminal

Comment: And `.desktop` file also works right?

Comment: I am not sure..How can I confirm that

Comment: Just double-click to run from file manager

Comment: it gives `Untrusted applicatiion launcher` error

Comment: Can you come to [chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) for discussion?

Answer (score 4):

My standard debugging flow for desktop entry file (.desktop application):

- file format - check if the desktop entry follow [the spec of freedesktop](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).
- executable command - if the previous check looks good, try your command of Exec in a terminal directly.
- executable as expected - if the previous check looks good, then double click the .desktop with your mouse.
- executing environment - if the previous check looks good, it means your execution command and .desktop should at least run in your desktop environment. Put it under ${HOME}/.config/autostart will definitely work.

[Additional Information]

1. What if it does still not work with all check passed and .desktop has been in ${HOME}/.config/autostart?

   - You may consider to redirect logs from your Exec in .desktop to see what special application behavior raised by your executable.
2. Why does ${HOME}/.config/autostart work but not /etc/xdg/autostart?

   - There are possible root causes. The most common case is that your executable needs to read or manipulate user-specific files/directories/config/cache/environment. For example, an autostart applet wants to write something in $HOME/.cache. Trigger .desktop in $HOME/.config/ will make sure the executable is triggered with a known $HOME.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and Paste the `.desktop` file to `/home/'user'/.config/autostart/`, e.g. `/home/rumi/.config/autostart/app.desktop` where `rumi` is the user and `app.desktop` is the `.desktop` file.

Should work fine.

Comment: how to debug if "should work fine" becomes "doesn't work fine"?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Copied some desktop file that chrome created using the "Add to desktop" feature.