# Autostarted .desktop application doesn't exit on log out

Tags: ubuntu, .desktop, autostart

I'm following the answer of [Autostarting .desktop application at startup not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256929/autostarting-desktop-application-at-startup-not-working), and it is working well.  I'm launching a python script.  The `.desktop` application looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Autostart Script
Exec=shutdown_notify.py
Icon=system-run
```

This is working well - but if I log out and log in I see the first instance of my script is still running.

```
$ ps -C shutdown_notify.py
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4026 ?        00:00:01 shutdown_notify
25421 ?        00:00:00 shutdown_notify
```

Is there a way to make sure the script exits on log out?  Do I need to add logic to quit on log out?

---

Update with `logind.conf` info as requested by @binarysta

```
$ grep -E 'KillUserProcesses|KillOnlyUsers|KillExcludeUsers' /etc/systemd/logind.conf
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
```

---

Update, I have two autostart files: one launches the python script above, the other launches `gnome-terminal`.  After a reboot I see:

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep -E "gnome-terminal|shutdown_notify"
training  6495  0.9  0.1  84936 29360 ?        S    07:13   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/shutdown_notify.py
training  6565  0.7  0.2 622880 34448 ?        Sl   07:13   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
training  9647  0.0  0.0  13264  2564 pts/0    S+   07:13   0:00 grep --color=auto -E gnome-terminal|shutdown_notify
```

Log out, log in, and I see:

```bsh
training  6495  0.1  0.1  85076 29360 ?        S    07:13   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/shutdown_notify.py
training 19110  3.1  0.1  84936 29636 ?        S    07:15   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/shutdown_notify.py
training 19141  2.3  0.2 696496 34584 ?        Sl   07:15   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
training 19421  0.0  0.0  13264  2696 pts/0    S+   07:15   0:00 grep --color=auto -E gnome-terminal|shutdown_notify
```

Comment: please provide `grep -E 'KillUserProcesses|KillOnlyUsers|KillExcludeUsers' /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Comment: @binarysta I've updated the question with the results of the grep

Comment: While it'd be interesting to know the rationale behind the design of a system that autostarts user programs at login without (by default) shutting them down at logout, using systemd `--user` units instead of `~/.config/autostart/` desktop entries is likely to give you grater control and flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `KillUserProcesses` is `no` by default in [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/logind.conf.5.html). This setting causes user processes not to be killed when the user completely logs out. To change this behavior in order to have all user processes killed on the user's logout, set `KillUserProcesses=yes` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and re-login.

current value can be checked by (it should be `true` after change)

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager KillUserProcesses
b true
```

**UPDATE**

The difference here between `gnome-terminal` (GUI Application) and `shutdown_notify.py` processes is, `gnome-terminal-server` process bound to the same TTY as all other X11 processes running. By logging out, the desktop environment and windowing system (x11) will be terminated so thats why `gnome-terminal` will exit.

Comment: Thanks @binarysta.  If I do something like `Exec=gnome-terminal` it does quit when I log out. Do you know what the distinction is between the python script and the terminal application is?

Comment: @russau what is `ps aux | grep -E "gnome-terminal|shutdown_notify"` after you login?

Comment: I just did exactly that experiment!  I've updated the question with the results.

Comment: @russau I updated the answer.